# Как избавится от артефакта?

Tags: css

На [тостер](https://toster.ru/q/570790) увидел вопрос и разумеется воспроизвёл эту проблему у себя на ПК и действительно оказалось так...

Вот проблема:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #121212;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.item {
  width: 300px;
  height: 450px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 14px;
  position: relative;
}

.description {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  z-index: 10;
}

p.head {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 900;
}

p.title {
  font-size: 14px;
}

p.head,
p.title {
  color: #fbfbfb;
}

.item:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 5%, #121212 85%);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://st.kp.yandex.net/im/poster/1/2/2/kinopoisk.ru-Gamer-1222188--o--.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="description">
      <p class="head">
        Lorem ipsum dolor
      </p>
      <p class="title">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam dolor doloribus molestiae numquam quaerat!
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://st.kp.yandex.net/im/poster/2/5/3/kinopoisk.ru-The-DUFF-2535486--o--.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="description">
      <p class="head">
        Lorem, ipsum.
      </p>
      <p class="title">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, quo.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://st.kp.yandex.net/im/poster/2/7/8/kinopoisk.ru-Equals-2781202--o--.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="description">
      <p class="head">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
      </p>
      <p class="title">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

На скриншоте плохо видно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но вот на [fiddle](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/XxeaLN?editors=1100) видно очень хорошо эти останки фотки

Как надо поступить в этом случае - что бы не было видно эти огрызки ?

Comment: даже здесь в сниппете это видно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Уберите `overflow:hidden` (потому что не обрезает, а *"обгрызает"* картинки) :

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

html,body{
  height:100vh;
}

img{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  border-radius: 14px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

body{
  background:#121212;
}

.items{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
}

.item{
  width:300px;
  height:450px;
  border-radius:14px;
  position: relative;
}

.description{
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding:10px 20px;
  z-index:10;
  border-radius: 0 0 14px 14px;
}

p.head{
  font-size:24px;
  font-weight:900;
}
p.title{
  font-size:14px;
}

p.head,p.title{
  color:#fbfbfb;
}

.item:after{
  content:"";
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 5%,#121212 85% );
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://st.kp.yandex.net/im/poster/1/2/2/kinopoisk.ru-Gamer-1222188--o--.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="description">
      <p class="head">
        Lorem ipsum dolor 
      </p>
      <p class="title">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam dolor doloribus molestiae numquam quaerat!
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://st.kp.yandex.net/im/poster/2/5/3/kinopoisk.ru-The-DUFF-2535486--o--.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="description">
      <p class="head">
        Lorem, ipsum.
      </p>
      <p class="title">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, quo.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://st.kp.yandex.net/im/poster/2/7/8/kinopoisk.ru-Equals-2781202--o--.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="description">
      <p class="head">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
      </p>
      <p class="title">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

А `border-radius` задайте картинке и описанию.

Comment: нет , вопрос не решился ....